# Azure-identity APIs logging too much logs

Tags: java, azure, logging, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am using azure-identity to authenticate and microsoft-graph apis to fetch data from Microsoft Teams. Somehow azure-identity APIs are logging too much unwanted logs, those repetitive and not much of having important information, just like below.

```
    2022-12-19 20:51:05.256  INFO 28050 --- [ol-1-worker-105] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.256  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-69] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.256  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-69] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.256  INFO 28050 --- [ol-1-worker-105] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.357  INFO 28050 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.358  INFO 28050 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.387  INFO 28050 --- [Pool-1-worker-3] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.387  INFO 28050 --- [Pool-1-worker-3] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.513  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-59] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.513  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-59] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.566  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-69] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.566  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-69] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.614  INFO 28050 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.614  INFO 28050 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.662  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-21] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.663  INFO 28050 --- [ool-1-worker-21] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2022-12-19 20:51:05.678  INFO 28050 --- [ol-1-worker-103] c.m.a.msal4j.AcquireTokenSilentSupplier  : Returning token from cache
2022-12-19 20:51:05.678  INFO 28050 --- [ol-1-worker-103] c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
```

My pom.xml entry for azure-identity and microsoft-graph is as below.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
<artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
<version>5.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My Question is, is there any way to stop those logs, is there any way to control it?

Answer (score 0):

Found this as I am looking for the same solution.

Looks like Microsoft  requires an extra hoop to jump through to control the logging level of the MSAL library.

For Java:
This involves creating a logging XML file and pointing to it with a System.properties setting. Setting the level to "error" or "warn" should stop these messages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging-java

If your solution is not using Java, see this link for other implementations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#logging

****edit

To add, the solution I implemented for this:
Create an XML file and point to it with
System.setProperty("logging.config", "/absolute/path/to/file.xml");

contents of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks @peter, but this is not solving  the issue

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hmmm I'm using an embedded log4j2 within apache camel and had already have `com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSession`, `com.azure.messaging.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusReceiveLinkProcessor` & `com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ActiveClientTokenManager` set for WARN level in the `log4j2.properties` file.

Comment: @user3788685
Apologies, was late for me and posted wrong.


So I created a xml file with the content below, then pointed to the file with

System.setProperty("logging.config", "/absolute/path/to/file.xml");


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>    
</configuration>

Comment: sorry that didn't work either so am in the same situation as @Gunwant